# I upgraded from android 2.2 to 3.1.2 and it was showing error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-manifest

I upgraded from android studio 2.2 to 3.1.2 and my old files are showing me error. I don't know how to resolve the issue

Error

error: unknown element  found

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:name=".SplashTimer"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".VerificationActivity">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DashboardActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".ProblemsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".TotalActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".FirstPayment"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".FirstPaymentInformation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".DeclineQuestionsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".LIkelyProblemsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".TotalAmountActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".ThanksActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".SignUpActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SignUpTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".StripePayment" />
    <activity
        android:name=".PaymentActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_payment"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <activity android:name=".LocationActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".SecondPayment" />

    <activity android:name=".DriverPayment"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity><!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
 App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

This is my manifest and I have checked the manifest but I don't know what the error is. I have tried checking if the manifest is not compatible with android studio 3.1.2

Comment: Trust me, the problem isn't in the `AndroidManifest.xml` but in `gradle` file, `gradle.properties` files and the local downloaded old gradle version.

Comment: @jantursky how do I download old gradle version

Comment: You need to downgrade the gradle version, but why will you do that?

Comment: Is there any other way apart from downgrading my gradle version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a closing tag on

```
<activity android:name=".VerificationActivity">
```

In previous version the misplaced tags were ignored or generated only a warning. Since Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0 AAPT2 is enabled by default. Documentation available at:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration